# How to transfer a html file from Azure VM via Azure powershell or Azure CLI to a local machine

Tags: nunit, devops, azure-powershell, azure-cli, pester

I am working on developing a Automated QA script for my project for my organisation. My goal is to execute pester scripts through custom script extension feature of azure vms. I got the Pester executed and result exported as a nunit xml.  I would like to fetch the xml back from VM to my local machine. One way of doing that is by uploading the xml into blob storage from VMs. but since it requires azure connection to be established in VM using SP account. I dont prefer this method.

I would like to know the best way to retrive pester results and get it outside VM. 
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a shared access signature token for that ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1)). that way your script doesnt really need SP, it just needs the token. that token would limit permissions to only upload file to specific container (or even blob).

```
$sascontext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName accountname -SasToken '?tokenvalue'
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File path -Container name -Context $sascontext -Force
```

You can create new token with `New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken` or `New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken`

Your only requirement would be to install Azure.Storage module before hand.

Comment: I will try this and update you. Thanksalot for reply